# Problem with logging things from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have a problem with logging something from an array. I need to find the highest rated locations from each place and i need to log the name and coordinates from those 3 locations. I have been stuck here for a while now anyone know how to do this?

this is the code i already have:

```
let locaties = [
    {naam: 'locatie1', type: 'cafe', rating: 8, coordinaat: {lat: 17, lon: 3},},
    {naam: 'locatie2', type: 'winkel', rating: 3, coordinaat: {lat: 23, lon: 9},},
    {naam: 'locatie3', type: 'Restaurant', rating: 7, coordinaat: {lat: 3, lon: 17},},
    {naam: 'locatie4', type: 'winkel', rating: 7, cordinaat: {lat: 20, lon: 10},},
    {naam: 'locatie5', type: 'cafe', rating: 1, coordinaat: {lat: 12, lon: 13},},
    {naam: 'locatie6', type: 'winkel', rating: 5, coordinaat: {lat: 13, lon: 2},},
    {naam: 'locatie7', type: 'Restaurant', rating: 6, coordinaat: {lat: 7, lon: 17},},
    {naam: 'locatie8', type: 'Restaurant', rating: 2, cordinaat: {lat: 3, lon: 15},},
    {naam: 'locatie9', type: 'cafe', rating: 4, coordinaat: {lat: 30, lon: 12},},
    {naam: 'locatie10', type: 'winkel', rating: 9, cordinaat: {lat: 27, lon: 19},},
];

Object.keys(locaties).forEach(key => {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(locaties[key].naam);
})
```

Comment: A solution might be to sort you array by rating, and pick the 3 last elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Semi-related, but instead of `Object.keys(locaties).forEach(key =>` it's simpler and more efficient to just use `locaties.forEach((value, key) =>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let locations = [{
    name: 'locatie1',
    type: 'cafe',
    rating: 8,
    coordinate: {
      lat: 17,
      lon: 3
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'locatie2',
    type: 'winkel',
    rating: 3,
    coordinate: {
      lat: 23,
      lon: 9
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'locatie3',
    type: 'Restaurant',
    rating: 7,
    coordinate: {
      lat: 3,
      lon: 17
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'locatie4',
    type: 'winkel',
    rating: 7,
    coordinate: {
      lat: 20,
      lon: 10
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'locatie5',
    type: 'cafe',
    rating: 1,
    coordinate: {
      lat: 12,
      lon: 13
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'locatie6',
    type: 'winkel',
    rating: 5,
    coordinate: {
      lat: 13,
      lon: 2
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'locatie7',
    type: 'Restaurant',
    rating: 6,
    coordinate: {
      lat: 7,
      lon: 17
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'locatie8',
    type: 'Restaurant',
    rating: 2,
    coordinate: {
      lat: 3,
      lon: 15
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'locatie9',
    type: 'cafe',
    rating: 4,
    coordinate: {
      lat: 30,
      lon: 12
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'locatie10',
    type: 'winkel',
    rating: 9,
    coordinate: {
      lat: 27,
      lon: 19
    },
  },
];

highest_rated_locations = locations
  .sort((a, b) => b.rating - a.rating) // order elements by rating descending. Note: the original locations array changes, since the sort method is mutable, if the original array shouldn't be changed, use Array.from
  .slice(0, 3) // return the first three elements of the array

for (const location of highest_rated_locations) {
  console.log(`Name: ${location.name} | Lattitude: ${location.coordinate.lat} | Longitude: ${location.coordinate.lon}`)
}
```

I adjusted some names in the code for better understanding. For some explanation, `Object.keys()` returns all the keys of the given Object. In your case this is an array and the values will be `0, 1, 2, ...`. If you would do this with one of the objects inside the array, for example `Object.keys(locations[0])` you would get the following: `name, type, rating, coordinate`. `lat` and `lan` won't be in there since those are nested properties of `coordinate`. I would suggest to you, that you inform yourself a bit about javascript loops, since they are pretty important.